# Pine script strategy.exit to alertcondition

Tags: pine-script

I have a problem with pine script

I've converted a strategy to study, but I really dont know how `strategy.exit()` `trail_offset` works.

```
tick=input(0.01,title="Ticker size",type=input.float)
ts_calc = close * (1/tick) * ts * 0.01
strategy.exit("ExitLong", "RSILong", trail_points=0, trail_offset=ts_calc)
```

how can i convert this to an `alertcondition`?

Answer (score 1):

`strategy.exit` is only applicable for strategy. `indicator(pine5)` or `study(pine4)` can not have `strategy.exit` and `strategy.entry` calls.

If your aim is just to create the alert, you need to create a trailing stop use `alertcondition(condition = crossunder(close, trailingStop)`

Something of this sort.